# Class SecurityConfig without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm taking a spring course and the professor is using an older version of spring boot. I'm trying to use a recent version, however it has some differences in the security part that I'm having trouble with.

The biggest problem is in the implementation of SecurityConfig without extending WebConfigurerAdapter.

**This is the teacher's example:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = { "/h2-console/**" };

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test")) {
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(PUBLIC_MATCHERS).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

**And this is what I did: **

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig  {
private static final String[] PUBLIC_MATCHERS = {"/h2-console/**"};

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); //desliga a protecao a csrf, o que permite executar metodos POST,PUT,DELETE sem sessao de usuario
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console()).permitAll().and().headers().frameOptions().disable(); //libera acesso ao h2-console
http.cors();

return http.build();
}
```

When I try to access "http://localhost:8080/h2-console/" it's working normally, but if I try to access something different, the error **403 Forbidden** is returned.

According to the course, if I try to access something different than "h2-console" it should redirect to a login page (browser) or returns the error **401 Unauthorized** (postman)  , example:
[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbqoY.png)

What should I change to work as expected ?

Comment: Are you using spring boot version 3?

Comment: Yes, I am.  <version>3.0.4</version>

Comment: so you have to upgrade your security config code for spring boot 3. In spring boot 3 some methods and annotations are deprecated. You can take reference from my code. Answer is available below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable frameOptions and allow h2 endpoints. Also if you will use swagger etc you have to allow its endpoints too. Here is working example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

  ............
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.antMatchers("/api/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
                    auth.antMatchers("/api/user").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/public",
                "/h2-console/**",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui.html/**",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/swagger-ui/**",
                "/v3/api-docs/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using sprint boot version 3 and antMatchers it's not avaiable.

Answer (score 0):

Security config file :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    private final JwtFilter filter;

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint point;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeRequests().
                requestMatchers("/category/add")
                .authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/authenticate","/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

 @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new CustomAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

CustomAuthentcationManager

```
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```